# Magento Camel Case Conversion

Tags: magento

I have a column name productId. After retrieving collection from magento model, I need to retrieve this productId. I do $product->getProductId(). Its not working. However if change column name to productid and I do $product->getProductid(), it works fine. How should I retrive this column value.
P.S. I can't change the column name to productid or product_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'magic' getters are just a wrapper for getData, try `$product->getData('productId')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your column name must be product_id if you want: $product->getProductId() or $product->getData('product_id').
If you use productId as column name, you can't use magical $product->getProductId()